# Swift main loop for updating a view

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm new to Swift and trying to implement a simple test Single-View app: Upon running, it should keep appending text lines in a `UITextView` automatically.

However, all I get is a blank screen with the following code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var m_logView: UITextView!

    private let m_log = Log()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addLog(msg: "Hello World!")

        while true {
            m_log.requestLog{ [weak self] (data: String) in
                self?.consumeLog(log: data)
            }
        }
    }

    func consumeLog(log: String) {
        addLog(msg: log)
    }

    func addLog(msg: String) {
        m_logView.text += msg + "\n"
    }
}

class Log {
    func requestLog(consume: (_ log: String) -> Void) {
        let log = "Data from wherever"
        consume(log)
    }
}
```

I suspected that I'm trying to update the `UITextView` at a wrong place. The above code simply blocks the `viewDidLoad()` from completing itself and showing the `UITextView`.

So I found `viewDidAppear`, but this time it gets stuck there and shows only "Hello World!" in the view.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var m_logView: UITextView!

    private let m_log = Log()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addLog(msg: "Hello World!")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        while true {
            m_log.requestLog{ [weak self] (data: String) in
                self?.consumeLog(log: data)
            }
        }
    }

    func consumeLog(log: String) {
        addLog(msg: log)
    }

    func addLog(msg: String) {
        m_logView.text += msg + "\n"
    }
}

class Log {
    func requestLog(consume: (_ log: String) -> Void) {
        let log = "Data from wherever"
        consume(log)
    }
}
```

Most iOS MVC tutorials I found teach how to implement the user interactions, but stay away from  how to update the view by programmtically changing the model from the backend.

I'm probably looking for a callback/delegate where I can refresh `UITextView` linked with its data model whenever the data changes, but where is it?

Comment: what do you see when you try to debug it? did you try visual debugger?

Comment: @Lu_ It's simply stuck inside the while loop forever, calling `requestLog` over and over.

Comment: So remember about first thing, you should put UI updates on main thread, and second, what exactly you want to see on screen when you add empty lines to text view? :D

Comment: @Lu_ hmm, are you saying that I'm doing things on a separate thread right now? If I call addLog(text) in viewDidLoad() I do see text on screen. What do you mean by "empty lines"?

Comment: Your app is stuck because you are running an infinite loop that never ends and your app is frozen. There should be a limit of number of lines.

Comment: you are adding only this: `msg + "\n"` so empty lines.

Comment: and you are just blocking thread

Comment: @Kamran I do intend to append lines indefinitely.

Comment: For that you should use `Timer` to schedule updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop is completely inappropriate because it causes a deadlock.

Use a `Timer` which works asynchronously

Replace

```
while true {
    m_log.requestLog{ [weak self] (data: String) in
        self?.consumeLog(log: data)
    }
}
```

with

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in 
    m_log.requestLog{ data in
        self?.consumeLog(log: data)
    }
}
```

And you might update the UI explicitly on the main thread

```
func addLog(msg: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        m_logView.text += msg + "\n"
    }
}
```

Note:

According to the Swift naming convention name variables *lowerCamelCased* for example `mLogView`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. Just realized that and implemented it with a Timer myself before seeing this answer.